# Jquery form submit validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jqxwidgets

I have following form:

```
<form id="testForm" action="country_Save">
   Country Name:<input type="text" id="countryName" />  
   <input type="submit" id='saveCountry' value="Add Country" />
</form>
```

and following JQuery for validating textfield

```
$('#testForm')
   .jqxValidator({  rules : [
          {
              input : '#countryName',
              message : 'Country Name is required!',
              action : 'keyup, blur',
              rule : 'required'
          }],
          theme : theme
});
```

How can i use this validation when I am submitting a form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this please:

```
     $('#testForm').on('submit', function() {
         return $('#testForm').jqxValidator('validate');
     });
```

Answer (score 12):

Bind a function to the `submit` event of the form. Return `false` in this function if any of the form fields fail validation.

For example:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    // do validation here
    if(/* not valid */)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: OK Thank you.can you please show an example using above jquery function.

Answer (score 1):

*Form validation* have a wide set of Javascript and jQuery libraries... My sugestion is a simple [jquery.com plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

PS:  `jqxValidator` is a method from the [jQWidgets framework](http://www.jqwidgets.com/)? if you (reader) not need so heavy/complex plugin, see bellow pure jQuery, else @Gajotres writed the best solution (!).

---

Using only jQuery and basic Javascript.

For both, "plug library" and "writing your own validation methods", first check if the direct use of jQuery is what you need.

Here a code that do all what the question say to need: validation on blur, keyup and "when submitting".

```
function validate(){
    var cnv = $('#countryName').val();
    if (!$.trim(cnv)) {
        alert('Country Name is required!');
        return false;
    } else { return true; }
}

$('#testForm').submit(validate);
$('#countryName').bind('blur keyup', validate);
```