# How do I trigger HTML5 validation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has multiple inputs which are validated with HTML5 validation. When I submit the form with by clicking the submit button it works fine.
However, when I want to submit this form using jQuery's `.submit()` it does not validate the form.

How can I force jQuery to validate the form before it is submitted?

Comment: Possibble Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541133/jquery-form-submit-validation)

Comment: @AshrithSheshan That question is about using a validation plugin, not HTML5.

Comment: No my question is that i validated all my forms with html5 required attribute so now i need to submit my form with jquery because i have put inputs for serial numbers that is checked with ajax if it is not exist in the database. so i need to submit my for with jquery and do call other functions after that which checks for correct serial number. when i submit with jquery the html5 validation is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to do a click on the submit button instead of submitting the form with JavaScript directly. So the validation should work as when you click on the button youself.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are doing the following steps and it fails.

```
$('#yourform').validate();
    if ($('#yourform').valid()) 
    {
        $('#yourform').submit();
}
```

If not, this shoud work.

You should open your site with Firefox, try to submit and press CTR+SHIFT+J. It will pop up the Java Error Console. Try to see if there isn't any syntax error.

Comment: He's not using a validation plugin, he's using the browser's built-in HTML5 validation.

Comment: Yes exactly i am using just html5 validations